# jQuery: stop a function to be execute

Tags: jquery, function

I'm using this plugin to create a raindrop [rain.js](https://github.com/juliocesar/rain.js)

All work great, but, I'm seeking a way to stop it when the user click on a link.

Please, someone has any advice?

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$("svg").toggle();
```

On executing it, rain hides. On executing it again, rain comes! To attach it to a link, you can do this way:

```
<a href="#" onclick="$('svg').toggle(); return false;">Hide / Show Rain</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The plugin is using `setTimeout` to create water droplets. Nice and simple -- just clear that timer!

```
clearTimeout(r.enginePid); // -- r = new Rain('id', cfg);
```

To start it up again, just re-set the intensity.

```
r.setIntensity(r.config.intensity);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/usa2pszr/3/